# $this -> cart->insert(); not working on live while working on localhost

Tags: codeigniter-2, cart

Hi i am having problem on my live server when i am checking the add to cart builtin function of CI. But its working fine on my localhost.
Here is my Model code where i am saving the cart

```
    $id     = $this->input->post('product_id'); // Assign posted product_id to $id
    $qty    = 1;// Assign posted quantity to $cty

    $this->db->from($this->table_name);
    $this->db->join($this->desc_table_name, "$this->desc_table_name.products_id = $this->table_name.id");

    $this -> db -> where('id', $id); // Select where id matches the posted id$this->db->from($this->table_name);
    $this -> db -> limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get(); // Select the products where a match is found and limit the query by 1

    // Check if a row has been found
    if($query->num_rows > 0){

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data = array(
                        'id'        => $id,
                        'qty'       => $qty,
                        'price'     => $row->price,
                        'name'      => "$row->title",
                    'options'       => array('description' => $row->description,'short_desc'=> $row->short_desc,'image'=>$row->image,),
            );
//print_r($data);
            $res = $this -> cart -> insert($data); 
            return TRUE;
        }
    // Nothing found! Return FALSE! 
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }`
```

and my ajax function is like this

```
   var link = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/youth_fashion/";
$(".add_item").click(function() {
    // Get the product ID and the quantity 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.post(link + "front/cart_controller/add_cart_item1", { product_id: id,  ajax: '1' },
        function(data){
        if(data == 'true'){
            $.get(link + "front/cart_controller/show_cart", function(cart){
                $("#cart_content").html(cart);
                var x = location.href;
                window.location.href= x;
            });

        }else{
            alert("Product does not exist");
        }   

     }); 

    return false;

});`
```

I am using CI 2.0. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. 
The issue is in session file (config.php). I am using the library of cart but it is not storing the data into table.
`$config['sess_use_database']   = TRUE;` i turned true and its storing and working for me